# Question on Han's conjecture

Tags: rt.representation-theory, homological-algebra

Let $A$ be a finite dimensional algebra with enveloping algebra $A^e$.
A conjecture of Han states that the Hochschild homology $Tor_{A^e}^n(A,A) \cong DExt_{A^e}^n(A,D(A))$ is nonzero infinitely often in case $A$ has infinite global dimension.

In case $A$ is symmetric one has an isomorphism from Hochschild homology to Hochschild cohomology $Ext_{A^e}^n(A,A)$ since $A \cong D(A)$ as bimodules.
Now in http://www.fsr.ac.ma/PACOM2017/Abstracts/Invited/Claude%20CIBILS.pdf I saw the statement that if the Hochschild homology vanishes for all but finitely many $n \geq 1$ and Han's conjecture is true, then it vanishes in fact for all $n \geq 1$.

Questions:

1. Can one show the same statement as in the link without the assumption that Han's conjecture is true at least for symmetric algebras? If yes, this would show that Han's conjecture is implied by the second Tachikawa conjecture and thus also the Nakayama and finitistic conjectures in the symmetric case.
2. Is the conjecture tested for the algebras $K<x,y,z>/(x^a,y^b,z^c,yx-qxy,zy-qyz,xz-qzx>$, where $a,b,c \geq 2$ are integers and $q$ a nonzero field element? This is motivated that the same question for Hochschild cohomology is negative by a similar example, and this example is symmetric so maybe it works. QPA "indicates" that the dimensions decrease but my computer dies when he tries to calculate $Ext_{A^e}^4(A,A)$ (I choosed a=b=c=2 and q=2 over the rationals)

edit: Changed the question 1.

Comment: Are you sure the claim is not simply that *if Han's conjecture is true* then vanishing in sufficiently large degrees implies vanishing in all degrees $\geq1$? I.e., just that Hochschild homology of algebras with finite global dimension is concentrated in degree zero? This is the statement made in Remark 2.23 of https://arxiv.org/abs/1703.02131 by the same authors.

Comment: @JeremyRickard Thanks, I changed the question 1. At least over perfect fields it should been trivial as stated before.

Comment: Question 2 is covered by Theorem 4.5 in *Hochschild homology and global dimension* by Bergh and myself.

Comment: @DagOskarMadsen Thanks, I just looked into the paper. But what if the field has characteristic nonzero? But that covers the example I did with the computer.

Comment: It should hold for high enough characteristic by the same methods as in the paper. For low nonzero characteristic there is no similar theorem yet, as far as I know.

Comment: You should also keep in mind that homology is a functor. It seems that the identity algebra homomorphism on $K[x]/(x^a)$ factors through the algebra in question 2? Then the Hochschild homology of  $K[x]/(x^a)$ (which is infinite) will be a direct summand of the Hochschild homology of $A$.